# Dividing one count() by another

Tags: mysql, sql

Trying to obtain a percentage value from an SQL query by dividing the number of rows where IsComplete = 1 with the total number of rows. How can I achieve this?

Database table:

[image: table]

Comment: `avg(IsComplete = 1)`.

Comment: I think that we should make the church of @GordonLinoff and worship regularly. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the value is always 0 or 1, you can sum the values and divide by the count, as in:

`SELECT SUM(IsComplete) / COUNT(*) AS percent_complete FROM centraldb.project;`

Multiplying by 100 if you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

Since null aren't used in aggregate functions try this:

```
select count(case when isComplete = 1 then isComplete end) / count(*)
  from project
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT sum(case when isComplete =1 then 1 else 0)/
       count(*)*100  as percentComplete
FROM project
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do

```
SELECT ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM centraldb WHERE IsComplete = 1) / COUNT(*)) AS percentage FROM centraldb;
```

#### [For example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/41b97/3)